# How can I make a calendar entry repeat yearly on the weekend before Christmas

Tags: calendar, ical

Making calendar items repeat has many options, but I can't figure out how to schedule an event on the third advent Sunday. Meaning the Sunday two weeks before Christmas.

Is there any option to do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any option which allows to set repeating entries relative to a holiday or a specific day (in this case "second Sunday before Dec 25"). Would a script to generate .ics files help to solve the problem?

Comment: FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=24,23,22,21,20,19,18;BYWEEKDAY=SA,SU

Comment: @AuberonVacher Thank you for the comment. I'm trying to implement that but can't get it to work. This is what I do: 1) create event in 2019 and make it repeat yearly. 2) Drag it to my desktop. 3) edit the ics file in atom 4) replace both `RRULE:FREQ=...` strings with `RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=17,16,15,14,13,12,11;BYWEEKDAY=SU`  5) import it back into ical. Result: It repeats yearly on the 14th and ignores the weekday